# How to clear CountDownTimer from onTick method?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have implemented the timer functionality in android app, I able to finish the timer from other local methods by calling `timerObject.cancel()` . Its working perfectly.

But when I tried to call same in `onTick()` method for specific condition, i am not able to cancel the timer, it last till the timer time ends.

How can i cancel the timer?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Gautier/737759

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for `CountDownTimer` it is easy to see why it is not working. `cancel()` merely removes the message for ticking the timer from the queue. But the message handler that gets called at each tick posts a message for the next tick after calling `onTick()`. So either you have to call `cancel()` outside of `onTick()`, via a `Handler` for example, or switch to using the Timer class instead.

Answer (score 0):

if using RXJava2. this code can help you.

```
    public abstract class CountDownTimer { 

    private TimeUnit timeUnit;
    private Long startValue;
    private Disposable disposable;

    public CountDownTimer(Long startValue,TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
        this.startValue = startValue;
    } 

    public abstract void onTick(long tickValue);

    public abstract void onFinish(); 

    public void start(){ 
        io.reactivex.Observable.zip( 
                io.reactivex.Observable.range(0, startValue.intValue()), io.reactivex.Observable.interval(1, timeUnit), (integer, aLong) -> {
                    Long l = startValue-integer;
                    return l; 
                } 
        ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
                .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() { 
                    @Override 
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) { 
                        disposable = d; 
                    } 

                    @Override 
                    public void onNext(Long aLong) { 
                        onTick(aLong); 
                    } 

                    @Override 
                    public void onError(Throwable e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } 

                    @Override 
                    public void onComplete() { 
                        onFinish(); 
                    } 
                }); 
    } 

    public void cancel(){ 
        if(disposable!=null) disposable.dispose();
    } 
}
```

using:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_activity);

        new CountDownTimer(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) {

            @Override 
            public void onTick(long tickValue) {
                Log.d("CountDown", "Remaining: " + tickValue);

                // cancel();
            } 

            @Override 
            public void onFinish() { 
                Log.d("CountDown", "The End!! ");
            } 
        }.start();
    } 
}
```

the owner of the code https://gist.github.com/chemickypes/fa3b7fc5b5a00a3ce37fee5815018702