# How to countDownTimer.cancel(); in OnTick(); function

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

Hi i am trying to cancel a countdown timer in On-tick function, It is working fine in lollipop but not working in Kitkat and below. How cancel it from a OnTick() function.

```
private void startTimer(final int minuti) {

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * minuti * 1000 + sec * 1000,
                500) {


            @Override
            public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {


        CountDownTimer.cancel();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();

    }
```

Comment: Please provide some code to give us something to work with..

Comment: Please check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Somehow if you call `countdowntimer.cancel` of a `CountDownTimer` object in its own `onTick` method it won't work!

The simplest way to solve your problem is defining another `CountDownTimer`, same as the main one, in order to check the condition to call `countdowntimer.cancel`. The point is that you are calling objects cancel method from outside of its own `onTick` method.

Check the example below:

```
CountDownTimer countdowntimer;
CountDownTimer assist;
long millisuntillfinish = 10000;
int interval = 100;
countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(millisuntillfinish, interval) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // if(true) countdowntimer.cancel(); (doesnt work)
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    }
};

assist = new CountDownTimer(timertillfinish, timerinterval) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if (true) {
            countdowntimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        assist.cancel();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is more than 6 years old, but calling `super.cancel();` within `onTick()` did the trick for me.

Leaving this here for the next unfortunate soul looking for an answer to this question.

ie.

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if(someCondition)
            super.cancel();
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        //do something else 
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
                    
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        
                        if (((millisUntilFinished/1000)%5)==0){ //every 5 sec
                            if(true)
                            {
                                this.cancel();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        //do somethhing
                    }
                }.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

I have been looking around and I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322633/how-to-clear-countdowntimer-from-ontick-method) where they call to the cancel() method in the onTick() using an alternative to the Android countDownTimer.

I had also this problem, and I created a global variable of a countDownTimer and I called to the cancel method in the activity when I needed, like `myCountDownTimer.cancel()`.

```
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;


private CountDownTimer createTimer(){
   return new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

       //do what you want
    }

    public void onFinish() {
       //do what you want
    }

    }.start();
}
```

In your activity call:

```
mCountDownTimer = this.createTimer();
```

And if you want to cancel it:

```
mCountDownTimer.cancel();
```

Comment: Sure, but I don't know the condition needed to call the cancel method. If you explain me I will do it. But you have to call mCountDownTimer.cancel() outside the method createTimer(), I think.