# Pausing and Resuming a count down timer and progress bar in android?

Tags: java, android, timer, progress-bar, countdowntimer

> I am making a simple app which uses a count down timer,Circular
>   progress bar and 3 buttons start, Pause and Resume.What I am trying to
>   do is when a particular activity starts and I press pause it stores
>   the time at which the timer was paused and resume from that point
>   forward.But the problem is the count down timmer doesn't stop so if I
>   pause at say 7 sec the progress bar stops at 7sec but when I press
>   resume it starts from whatever the count down timer value is at that
>   moment.This is the code I am trying to implement.

```
  btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //When user request to pause the CountDownTimer
                isPaused = true;

                //Enable the resume and cancel button
                btnResume.setEnabled(true);
                //Disable the start and pause button
                btnStart.setEnabled(false);
                btnPause.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });



btnResume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Disable the start and resume button

        btnStart.setEnabled(false);
        btnResume.setEnabled(false);
        //Enable the pause and cancel button
        btnPause.setEnabled(true);

        //Specify the current state is not paused and canceled.
        isPaused = false;
        isCanceled = false;
        mCountDownTimer.start();
}
    });
```

And this is code for the count down timer.

```
 private void neck_rotations()
    {
        neckRotation = true;
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(NECK_ROTATION_TIME, 1000)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {

                if (isPaused || isCanceled)
                {
                    paused_at = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                } else
                {
                    timeRemaining = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    donutProgress.setMaxValue(NECK_ROTATION_TIME / 1000);
                    donutProgress.setValueAnimated((int) timeRemaining);
                    counter.setText(String.valueOf(timeRemaining));

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                response = "Jumps";
                rest(response);

            }
        };
        mCountDownTimer.start();
    }
```

I am new to programming so any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this:

[How to clear CountDownTimer from onTick method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322633/how-to-clear-countdowntimer-from-ontick-method)

I'm not sure you can disable the timer from still counting down from the inner onTick() method.

Make a gloabl reference for the CountDownTimer and only call start() or cancel() from the clickListeners on that reference.

Comment: Yes I have made the count down timer global.I am using the same count down timer for 3 different methods.neck_rotation(),hand_rotation() and jumps() so when the user clicks start the 1st method gets called and on finish there is rest for 10 sec after every method.

Comment: As I see it, you are creating a new CountDownTimer when you press on btnResume and you also have mCountDownTimer as a reference to another CountDownTimer. Why is that ? Keep using the mCountDownTimer for the onClick() also. Anyway, the cancel() function should not be called from within the onTick() function.

Comment: Yes thats right can you help?Can you give a example or something?

Comment: Please refer to the link I've provided, there is a good solution for your needs.

Comment: I tried that solution it has cancel and start methods but no resume method and according to that example cancel is not supposed to be called from onTick but from outside I tried that so now when I click on resume it restarts the timer.How do i implement a resume functionality here can you help?